# Cannot convert python file (which contains selenium) to exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to convert python file to exe file.
I've used pyinstaller.

**Steps I followed:**

- I opened the cmd in the folder where is my script
- I used the next comand: pyinstaller --onefile -w name.py

And I got the below error when I want to open exe. I want to mention that I use selenium to open a Mozilla Firefox Browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym6Hb.png)

Comment: Is your script `name.py` importing anything? Such as `from selenium import webdriver`.

Comment: Yes, there is on the first line `from selenium import webdriver`

Comment: You are using `pyinstaller --onefile` on something that needs more than one file.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the executable, update the driver path in `name.spec` file and update the executable. such as

```
1.binaries=[('path\chromedriver.exe', '.')]
2.pyinstaller name.spec
```

Also, make sure that you have changed the chrome path accordingly.

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
  # executed as a bundled exe, the driver is in the extracted folder
  chromedriver_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "chromedriver.exe")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
```

this will allow the executable to fetch chrome driver from the system path.

Comment: I am using Mozila firefox. Do I have to add that `if getattrt(..):..` in my code?

Comment: anyways you have to check the driver path in system path while running the executable.